# After updating to 7.27, updates don't work and Status says cannot verify Drupal core

Tags: drush, updating

I upgraded my site to 7.27 using drush, and my website says that it is running 7.27 under the "modules" admin page.

However, when I get a status report, it says "No update data available.
No update information available. Run cron or check manually."

So I run the cron there, and it will turn green and read "Drupal 7.27" but if I try to run update my modules it just stops the page after saying "checking for updates" and the status report reads the above error again instead of reading "Drupal 7.27".

I've rebuilt the registry, and I am at a loss as what to do now.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can and should accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. It was a javascript error with the "Colorbox" library. Apparently the colorbox library was two years old and became incompatible due to the switch from .live to .on. All issues were solved when I updated my colorbox library.